# How to make a list of words?

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart, random

I need to make a list containing words or phrases, then from this list I would like to randomly select an element and pass it to a variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `Random.nextInt([int? max])` method passing the length of the list as its `max` argument:

```dart
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
final res = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)];
```

When you pass the length of the sequence as the `nextInt` max argument, Random will return an integer value that is in a range between 0 (inclusive) and list length (exclusive).

Comment: To be more clear, the Random class is a part of the `dart:math` package